# Charge distribution and voltage

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

The dependence of the electric potential can be obtained from Poisson equation and in one dimension is,
$$
\nabla^2 V(x)=-\frac{\partial \mathrm{E}}{\partial x}=-\frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon \epsilon_0},
$$
where $\nabla^2$ is the Laplace operator, $V$ is the voltage, $E$ is the electric field, $\rho$ is the charge density, $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon_0$ are the permittivities of the sample and free space, respectively. Integrating, we obtain,
$$
E(x)-E(0)=-\int_0^h \frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon  \epsilon_0} \ d x,
$$
the voltage  is then given by
$$
V(h)= \int_{0}^{h} E(x)\ d x =\iint_{0}^{h} \frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon \epsilon_0} \ d x  \ d x
$$

This suggests that $V$ is only dependent on the charge density, not the location of charge.

Say I keep the same charge density but make some changes between to the location of charge - as in the figure below, I'd suggest that $V_{2}>V_{1} $ . Yet, the above equation would suggest that is false and $V_{2} = V_{1}$. Why is the derivation wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that the second integral is indefinite? $V = V(x)$

Comment: Apologies, corrected.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer relate to including not just the x, but also the y axis in your calculations? Since in your images, the charges are distributed 2-dimensionally.

Answer (score 1):

> Integrating, we obtain,
> $$
> E(x, t)-E(0, t)=-\int_0^h \frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon  \epsilon_0} \ d x,
> $$
> the voltage  is then given by
> $$
> V(h) =\iint_{0}^{h} \frac{\rho(x)}{\epsilon \epsilon_0} \ d x  \ d x
> $$

I'm pretty sure what you've done here is rediscovered Gauss's Law.

One thing you glossed over is that reducing the problem to one dimension depends on the geometry being uniform and extending "to infinity" in the other two directions. That is we assume that $\rho(x, y, z) = \rho(z)$.

That means that your depiction in "Arrangement 1" can't be reduced to a one-dimensional problem.

If you assumed that each charge indicated in that drawing extended uniformly to infinity in the y and z directions, however, it would be correct that the potential for z > h and z < 0 doesn't depend how the charges are arranged in the interval 0 < z < h. This is an immediate consequence of Gauss's Law.

Comment: Assuming the infinite plane then - why do people then talk of the separation of charge generating a voltage? If I put a voltmeter across arrangement 1 and arrangement 2 - would it really read the same number?..I feel I am missing something obvious here...

Comment: @Tomi, if the plates were made of a conductive material, then drawing a + charge to the bottom side of the top plate would leave a - charge on top surface of that plate. Drawing a - charge to the top surface of the bottom plate would leave a + charge on its bottom surface. So the potential on the plates would not be equal to the potential in all the space below the bottom plate or above the top plate.

Comment: I would agree! But now I've given a proof above in the original questions which suggests that the voltage *is* sensitive to the separation of charge ...but I don't understand how that is compatible with what we both derive from Gauss' law. I'm not sure we need to bring in the argument of the conductive materials here? (Or maybe I misunderstand).

Answer (score 1):

The voltage expression might be incorrect.

Referring to Jefimenko Equation (5-3.1), the electrostatic potential and charge distribution are related as,

$$
\phi = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int \frac{\rho}{r} dv' + \phi_0
$$

where $\phi$ is electrostatic potential.

Since the voltage between two points is the difference of potential at those,

$$
V = \phi - \phi_0
$$

We have,

$$
V = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int \frac{\rho}{r} dv'
$$

Voltage does depend on the location of charges in the distribution ($r$).

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment ($\epsilon_0=1$):

$$  \frac{dE(x)}{dx}= \rho(x) $$

so that the internal is definite:

$$ E(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x\rho(x')dx'= E(x) - E(-\infty) = E(x) $$

Where the field at infinity is zero.

The potential then comes from:

$$ -\frac{d V(x)}{dx} = E(x) $$

Repeat:

$$ V(x) = -\int_{-\infty}^xE(x')dx'= V(x) - V(-\infty)$$

Here we have gauge freedom to chose $V(-\infty)$ to be whatever we want. Zero if it's a Coulomb potential (which isn't quite right in 1D). It's more like an infinite sheet of charge, where the field is constant on each side, so $V(x) = qx$, and $V_{\pm\infty}\rightarrow \pm\infty$.

A sensible case is a single capacitor, which in 1D is two charges, $\pm q$ at $\pm d$, with a total voltage of $2qd$...for charge $q$...lets just say $V=q/C=2qd\rightarrow C=2d$, then you want $V(0) = 0$, and you'd set...idk you get the picture.

Comment: Thanks! - But - I'm not sure this exactly answers my question - does the separation of the "charge sheets" in this case, make a difference? I think, from this you would suggest that indeed, $V_{1} = V_{2}$...and the separation of charge makes no different at all. Only the NET charge density from -$\infty$ to $x$...which is what is surprising me. I thought $E$ would get stronger if you separated the charge.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question. Is 1D, or symmetric under 2 directions of translation? If either, then what does "depend on the location of he charge" mean? I think the fact that V=2d in my toy example, mean; yes, it depends on the location of the charge.

Comment: Sorry!...lets say the system is symmetric under 2 directions of translation, where the field goes to zero very far away. 

Would you not agree in your derived equation for V(x) it dependent on the *net* charge you are integrating over, the location of the charge doesn't come into it. (also see @ThePhoton's answer). 

Yet, we also agree that a capacitor (as you describe) will have an increased V over the two plates as a function of d. But I don't see how that works with Gauss' law, which allows us to say that V is dependent on just the net charge density...

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to use math notion, sorry about that, but since you're working in two dimensions, it looks like the Laplacian needs to include both an x and a y component:

∇*(∇(V)) = -(dEx/dx + dEy/dy)

This, I believe, would account for the two dimensional distribution of the charge in the potential values, so the two scenarios you've described would indeed have different potentials.

Comment: Moreover, even in 1D, rho = rho(x) means the charge is a function of position.

Comment: @Daniel you are supposed to use MathJax to post here. Basically the mathematics is written in like $TeX$ commands; its easy and you will have to learn it to be really successful on this forum. Google stuff on how to write math in $TeX$, get some cheat sheets and role with it. All you need are the commands themselves, you will not have to write document preambles, environments and all of that.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).